# error System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Sorry, we couldn't find xxx.xlsx. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?'

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I am tryiny to open an excel file using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel but i get this error :

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Sorry, we couldn't find C:\Users\user\test.xlsx. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?'

Here is my c# code :

```
Workbooks xlWorkBooks = null;
            Workbook xlWorkBook = null;
            Application xlApp = new Application();

            xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
            xlWorkBook = xlWorkBooks.Open(@"‪C:\Users\user\test.xlsx");
```

the excel file exists nad the name is correct.
I am using windows 10 / microsoft office 2013

Comment: do you have Excel installed on that server? Also, since most web servers run as x64 bits, then one has to assume you installed x64 bit office/Excel here. Either way, you do have to have Excel installed on the server. And to be fair, it is not recommended that you COM automate office programs this way - they tend to not be very thread safe.  But, the bit size of the office install will have to match what your code is running as. Do NOT use ANY CPU if you going to do this - force the project to x64 or at least the same bit size as what your final web server will be running as.

Answer (score 0):

User's files are protected, the application may not have permission to access the file. I had the same problem and solved it moving my test file to a folder in C:\ (for instance C:\ tests) where no special access permissions are needed.

Edit: files directly in the root folder have similar restrictions, hence the "tests" folder.